# How to return the value of column[0] on the second consecutive occurrence of "0" in column[1]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Question/Context**:
I am trying to make a code that will read each CSV file in the specified folder, look for the second consecutive occurrence of zero in column index [1], and display the corresponding value from column index [0] when found. Below is what I have so far but it is not working. It simply says that there are no columns with two consecutive zeroes. However, when I open the individual files, I can clearly see that there are columns with two consecutive zeroes.

**Current code**:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = "/content/drive/session 1 & 2"

def find_column1_value_for_second_zero(file_path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        consecutive_zeros = 0
        column1_value = None

        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            if row.iloc[1] == 0:
                consecutive_zeros += 1
                if consecutive_zeros == 2:
                    column1_value = row.iloc[0]
                    break
            else:
                consecutive_zeros = 0

        return column1_value
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading file '{file_path}': {str(e)}")
        return None

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):  # Assuming your files are CSV format
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        
        column1_value = find_column1_value_for_second_zero(file_path)
        
        if column1_value is not None:
            print(f"In file '{filename}', the value in column 1 for the second zero in column 2 is: {column1_value}")
        else:
            print(f"In file '{filename}', no second zero in column 2 was found.")
```

**Expected Result**: get the value in column [0] that is in the same row as the second consecutive zero in column [1].
**Actual Result**: each row returned "no second zero in column 2 was found."

Answer (score 1):

You can set `col0, col1 = df.columns[:2]`, and then use the following one-liner which uses the cumulative count of values in `col1`.

```
col1_value = df.loc[(df.groupby(col1).cumcount() == 1) & (df.col1 == 0), [col0]].values[0][0]
```

For the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
   col0  col1
0     1     1
1     2     0
2     3     0 # second consecutive occurrence of 0
3     4     2
4     5     2
5     6     0
6     7     0
7     8     0
8     9     2
9    10     2
```

`col1_value = 3` which corresponds to the second consecutive occurrence of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) window is useful for this.

- Create a boolean series representing the locations at which your column has value 0
- In a rolling window of length 2, sum that boolean series.
- Where that sum is 2, then both the current and previous values in the original data were 0.
- Find row of the first such occurrence.

```
# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(0, 100, 10), 'b': [1,1,0,2,0,0,9,0,0,2]})
```

```
    a  b
0   0  1
1  10  1
2  20  0
3  30  2
4  40  0
5  50  0  # <-- Looking for this row
6  60  9
7  70  0
8  80  0
9  90  2
```

Note that `idxmax` returns the index of the *first* occurrence.

```
idx = df.iloc[:, 1].eq(0).rolling(2).sum().eq(2).idxmax()
print(df.iloc[idx, 0])
```

```
50
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `df.shift()` to move the first zero-check to the same row as the second one:

```py
# Sample data from the answer by Stuart Berg
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(0, 100, 10), 'b': [1,1,0,2,0,0,9,0,0,2]})

print(df.loc[(df.b == 0) & (df.b.shift() == 0), 'a'].iloc[0])
```

```
50
```